# How to solve the error related to Malformed URL Exception in Java?

Tags: java, sql, database

I have an weird issue in `Java`, I am receiving the following error:

> "java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:
>   /src/test/resources/sqlScripts/MySql.sql"

The other scripts are ran with success in another tests.
My code in the test is:

```
public void MyTest(Retailer brand, Environment environment) throws SQLException, IOException {

        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(
                new SmbFile("/src/test/resources/sqlScriptsMySQL.sql",
                        new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("", "USER", "password")).getInputStream());
        DBUIProcedure script = new DBUIProcedure(
                DriverManager.getConnection(environment.getDBURL(), ESW_PLATFORM_USERNAME, ESW_PLATFORM_PASSWORD),
                false, false);
        script.runScript(reader);
```

Anyone any solution to this ?

Comment: You are missing a foreard slash in the url in your code near the end. But also you need a full url including the protocol (presumably https://)

Comment: There is no need for the URL, because my SQL script is on git server, in that location.                                                                                                     Thanks

Comment: I guess you're using [`new SmbFile(String url, NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth)`](https://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/api/jcifs/smb/SmbFile.html#SmbFile(java.lang.String,%20jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthentication)). The doc says that you need an url String, try for example`smb://src/test/resources/sqlScriptsMySQL.sql` or `file://...`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is in the error message: "no protocol"

Comment: I figure it out the solution, no longer a problem

Comment: It's great that you found a solution, but it would be nice when you can share it with us.